# Did the Death Eaters know about the refounded Order of the Phoenix in Book 5 or were Kingsley, Tonks, and Moody just seen as Aurors?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, order-of-the-phoenix

In *Order of the Phoenix* Kingsley, Tonks, Moody, Lupin, and Sirius break into the Ministry to save Team DA. Did Voldemort know Kingsley, Tonks and Mad-eye were in the Order or were they just seen as Aurors?

Comment: Sirius and Lupin weren't Aurors

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Yes, but I didn't ask about Sirius and Lupin, I asked about Mad-eye, Tonks, and Kingsley.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the Dark Lord knew about Order of the Phoenix and its members at that time.

Dumbledore summarized Severus Snape's job in that words:

> Do not think that I underestimate
> the constant danger in which you place yourself, Severus.
> To give Voldemort what appears to be valuable information while
> withholding the essentials is a job I would entrust to nobody but
> you.

Dumbledore openly admitted to stand against "reborn" Dark Lord and it was very likely he would engage old members of the Order and recruit new supporters. Snape as a double agent must have told the Dark Lord some details about the Order.